# Draw Text inside Arc CustomView

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, android-custom-view

i am trying to draw text inside of arc . code is as follows

```
  public Round(Context context, int totalSections, int activeSections, String mText) {
    super(context);
    int dpi = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
    float x = 0.25f;
    final float radius = x * (new Float(dpi));
    mRadius = Math.round(radius) + 20;
    mRect = new RectF(
            getWidth() + mStrokeWidth, getWidth() + mStrokeWidth, getWidth() + mRadius - mStrokeWidth, getWidth() + mRadius - mStrokeWidth
    );
    text = mText;
    mTotalSections = totalSections;
    mActiveSections = activeSections;
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mSectionDegree = 360 / mTotalSections;
    mSectionDegree -= mGap;
}


public void setmActiveSections(int mActiveSections) {
    this.mActiveSections = mActiveSections;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    float lastDegree = 270 + (mGap / 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < mTotalSections; i++) {
        if (i < mActiveSections) {
            mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            mPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        }
        canvas.drawArc(mRect, lastDegree, mSectionDegree, false, mPaint);

        lastDegree += mSectionDegree + mGap;
    }
    Paint mPaint1 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint1.setStrokeWidth(1);
    mPaint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint1.setTextSize(15);
    mPaint1.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

    canvas.drawText(text, 20,30, mPaint1);

}
```

how i can draw text which is centre of radius ... what happening is on different device text is not coming in centre of radius 
 [image]

in given image i want canvas.drawtext should where Text is present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your `onDraw()`

```
mPaint1.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
```

then the x parameter in `drawText` can just be the center x of the circle.  You should be able to use `mRect.centerX()` to get that value.

You should use `mRect.centerY()` for the y value too, except it needs to be adjusted. The y parameter is actually the text baseline, so if you want to center vertically as well as horizontally, you will have to check some values in the paint's `FontMetrics` to see how much to lower your y value so that the text looks centered vertically.

Comment: can give some more on FontMetrics ? how i should i set text size

Comment: mPaint1.setTextSize(10 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
 but this giving pix in some big devices

Comment: You might have to post some more image examples, because multiplying by the display density factor should work correctly.  Another approach might be to say "I want the text size to be 1/6 the size of the circle" and set the text size to be `mRect.height() / 6`.  I'm not sure what your exact requirement is for the text, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: problem is round is coming perfect but there is big rect so the round starting at left and empty space after that as that rect is taking any way that we can make only round and not to have rect .. so basically  round is in rect where rect size is bigger then round can we make it same @kris larson